# Geotools + OGR: FeatureIterator.next() blocks the execution

Tags: ogr, geotools

I am using geotools to read through some vector files in my gis project. I am trying to read FileGeoDatabase files as well as DXF and DWG.

The thing is, I am able to create the Metadata for the files, meaning I can read the features that are inside each one of them, but when I try to go througheach one of the features, the service stops working from the point I call the FeatureIterator.next() function.
Here is an example of my code:

```
OGRDataStoreFactory factory = new JniOGRDataStoreFactory();

      Map<String, String> connectionParams = new HashMap<>();
      connectionParams.put("DriverName", "OpenFileGDB");
      connectionParams.put("DatasourceName", fgdbFile.getAbsolutePath());
      DataStore store = factory.createDataStore(connectionParams);
      List<Name> layerNames = store.getNames();

      for (Name name : layerNames)
      {
        SimpleFeatureSource source = store.getFeatureSource(name);

        String layerName = name.toString();

        FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> featureIterator = source.getFeatures().features();

        while (featureIterator.hasNext())
        {

          //Everything works well until this point.
          SimpleFeature simpleFeature = featureIterator.next();

          //This log is never shown in the Service's logs
          log.info("Getting info for feature No. " + featcount++ + "/" + totalFeatures);

          SimpleFeatureType simpleFeatureType = simpleFeature.getFeatureType();
          Geometry geometry = (Geometry) simpleFeature.getDefaultGeometry();

          CoordinateReferenceSystem coordinateReferenceSystem = simpleFeatureType.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();

          if (coordinateReferenceSystem == null && geometry.getUserData() instanceof CoordinateReferenceSystem)
            coordinateReferenceSystem = (CoordinateReferenceSystem) geometry.getUserData();

          if (coordinateReferenceSystem != null)
            fileMetadataBuilder.setCrs(layerName, CRS.lookupIdentifier(coordinateReferenceSystem, true));

          fileMetadataBuilder.addGeometryType(layerName, geometry);

          for (AttributeDescriptor attributeDescriptor : simpleFeatureType.getAttributeDescriptors())
          {
            JDBCType jdbcType = DatabaseUtils.getSQLType(attributeDescriptor.getType().getBinding());

            if (jdbcType.equals(JDBCType.NULL) || jdbcType.equals(JDBCType.OTHER))
              continue;

            FileAttribute.FileAttributeBuilder fileAttributeBuilder = FileAttribute.builder();
            fileAttributeBuilder.originalName(attributeDescriptor.getLocalName());
            fileAttributeBuilder.standardizedName(DatabaseUtils.standardizeFieldName(attributeDescriptor.getLocalName()));
            fileAttributeBuilder.type(jdbcType);

            fileMetadataBuilder.addFileAttribute(layerName, fileAttributeBuilder.build());
          }
        }
        featureIterator.close();
      }
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: You need to turn up logging to finest and try again, then add the log output to the question

Comment: can you share the data file (or an example of it that also fails)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, mystery solved. The issue is that I am using a GDAL image with version 3.0.2, but Geotools doesn't support it, so, since I am using an abstraction layer, the exception is "cached" behind it and is never displayed. It would be nice to have a way to propagate the exceptions to the JNI layers so the user knows what's going on.